# How to import large Excel file table to MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, excel

I am trying to move my MS Access databases into a single database of MySQL. Each table has at least 50,000 rows and 70 columns. What is the best way to import the data to MySQL tables?

I tried exporting it first to Excel and using the 'MySQL for Excel' add-on but the data seems to large for it to handle efficiently. If there are better ways to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export your file to a TXT or CSV and then use this MySQL Command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/file.txt' INTO TABLE your_table;
```

Comment: I added a few more things in the command but this idea worked. Thanks!